# Can simply importing a header ever lead to run-time issues?

Tags: objective-c, runtime-error, header-files

I realize that doing this can lead to compile errors. But is an import always safe if no (new) compile errors or warnings arise? If I use an import statement (e.g. to remove duplicate protocol definition warning), could doing so, on it's own, ever change the run-time behavior? What checks (if any) are necessary to ensure invariability of operation after a new header import?

Comment: Could you be more specific because your question makes me think you don't understand what header files are.

Comment: Are you talking about `#import` or `@import`?

Comment: Ken, Andy, talking about #import.... in my particular case, I got a duplicate protocol definition warning, noticed that deleting the duplicate protocol led to "no known instance method for selector" errors. However I could fix this by #importing the header (containing the protocol declaration) into the implementation file where the errors appeared. Then I was wondering... what side effects that might have, and how to be sure there were none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, importing a header can lead to run-time issues.

For example, you may get a warning that a selector is unknown so the compiler is making assumptions about its signature. If you fix that warning by importing the relevant header, then that changes the code the compiler is emitting. Generally, it would change the code from broken to correct, but that nevertheless results in a run-time change.

If you use `#import`, then the header could define preprocessor macros that radically alter the subsequent code. For example, it could `#define setNeedsDisplay setHidden` or something.

The only way I can think of to verify that importing the header didn't alter the generated code is to examine the generated code and compare before and after. You can ask Xcode or `clang` to produce assembly from the compilation. You could also use `otool -tV` to disassemble the binaries (although that wouldn't show changes in, say, static data like strings).